# android studio cant open .sqlite database file

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm currently building my first app using android studio that accesses an external database. However the app is crashing and giving errors saying the database can not be opened.  I've followed videos on youtube but i still have the problem.

When I copy my database .sqlite file from my desktop and paste it into the assets folder I get an error "File was loaded in the wrong encoding: UTF-8".
I tried reloading the file in several encodings but I would always get the same error message.  I'm guessing this is the issue.

Any other tips or notes are also welcome and appreciated.

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/invain3219/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "partyprobeDB.sqlite";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;
    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{
            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
            //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){
            //database does't exist yet.
        }

        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
    // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
    // to you to create adapters for your views.

}
```

Comment: what is ' ; ' in   TableInfo.LOGIN_EMAIL + " = '" + email + "';" ???

Comment: It's used to end SQL queries but its not necessary.

Comment: Have you copied the database from the assets folder to the databases folder? e.g. [access .sqlite database in the assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30059236/access-sqlite-database-in-the-assets-folder)

Comment: I hadn't done that but i just created a copyDatabase method, following video instructions, but i still cant open the file.

Comment: Check to see if DB copy worked i.e is the App's DATA taking up any space (may have to check without and then with DB copy, obviously deleting data each time).

Answer (score 0):

This looks fine but try this:

```
"/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "databases/";
```

Basically, add a / after databases.

**EDIT:**

```
    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() {
    String myPath = DB_LOCATION + DATABASE_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    return null;
}
```

**COPY**

```
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_LOCATION + DATABASE_NAME;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
    int length;

    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tried this and still got the following error:          08-14 23:40:09.700 11525-11525/com.example.cody5.partyprobe E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 32456 of [bda77dda96]

Comment: Try:    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() {
        String myPath = DB_LOCATION + DATABASE_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        return null;
    }

Comment: Tried this and i still cant open the file.

Comment: Check that your database is in your databases folder. If not, maybe you forgot to copy it. See code above to copy it.

Comment: I add this method and still have the same problem.  BUT i did just now realize that when i paste my partyprobeDB.sqlite file into the assets folder there is a message that says "File was loaded in the wrong encoding: UTF-8". I've since tried multiple encodings (UTF-16, US-ASCII, etc) but i still get the warning with what ever encoding i choose.

Answer (score 0):

id is int so change like below is enough ,  you don't need like this `" WHERE " + TableInfo.INFO_USER + " = '" + id + "';"`

```
 int id = curs.getInt(0);

    curs = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TableInfo.TABLE_USER_INFO +
            " WHERE " + TableInfo.INFO_USER + " = " + id, null);
```